# Customize WP website specific column with CSS

Tags: customization, css

I would like to change the following sentence “CREATING STYLE FOR BETTER LIFE” to a different font (Rochester) and i have tried several CSS codes so far but none has worked for me so far.

Website: http://www.tarshim.com

Please tell me what CSS code should i use and where to apply it

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include [Rochester font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Rochester?selection.family=Rochester) from Google

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rochester" rel="stylesheet">
```

See [wp_enqueue_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) or maybe you can use your theme (set font rochester to a heading you dont use for example).

Add a class to that h2:

```
<h2 class="rochester-font">CREATING STYLE FOR BETTER LIFE</h2>
```

In your CSS:

```
.rochester-font {
  font-family: 'Rochester', cursive;
  /* other css */
}
```

Don't forget the browser caching! Use hard-refresh when you're testing CSS.

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: h2 is already being used for this line as well as another line and i only want to change the font of this one

Comment: I know, that's why i mention you have to add a Class to that specific `<h2>`. You can add that class to any `<h2>` that needs the Rochester font-family. Please follow my steps exactly and it will work.

Comment: I changed the CSS in my answer. Now you can use it for all `<element>` in your site.